# EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, javabeans, spring-el

I've been trying to write on Elasticsearch with Multiple Indexes. Currently I have installed Spring v5.2.3.RELEASE and Spring Boot v2.2.4.RELEASE.

I found several solutions that allow to use multiple indexes using Spring's SPEL technology but I can't make it work.

I currently have these files:

ElasticDBDbConfig.java

```
package edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.config;
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = { "edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.datamodel.elasticdb"})
public class ElasticDBDbConfig {

   @Value("${elasticsearch.protocol}")
   private String esProtocol;

   @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
   private String esHost;

   @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
   private int esPort;

   @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
   private String esClusterName;

   @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
     public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() { 
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(esHost,esPort,esProtocol)));
    }

@Bean
public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
    ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate = new 
    ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());

    elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(KPIElasticValue.class);

    return elasticsearchTemplate;
}
```

ConfigIndexBean.java

```
package edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@Component("configIndexBean")
public class ConfigIndexBean {

@Value("${elasticsearch.dummyIndex}")
private String indexName;

public String getIndexName() {
    return indexName;
}

public void setIndexName(String indexName) {
    this.indexName = indexName;
}

}
```

KPIElasticValue.java

```
package edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.datamodel.elasticdb;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = KPIElasticValueSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = KPIElasticValueDeserializer.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.config")
@Document(type = "_doc", indexName = "#{@configIndexBean.getIndexName()}")
public class KPIElasticValue {
```

Do you have any idea?

I also try

```
@Document(type = "_doc", indexName = "#{configIndexBean.getIndexName()}")
@Document(type = "_doc", indexName = "#{configIndexBean.indexName}")
```

The exception is:

EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'configIndexBean'

Comment: You mean, that you have index app-logs-1, app-logs-2, app-logs-3 and you want to request them all as it's a single index?

Comment: No, I have some indexes that depend on values coming to me through an API. Based on those values I would like to change index through the setter of the ConfigIndexBean class and write on the correct index through the repository.

Comment: No way actually. I can solve it on more high level where you have to dispatch request to appropiate index by simple `if (dispatchToIndexA) {use Document} else {DocumentB}` or by implement your own PostBeanProcessor and managin right index on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved like this:

ConfigIndexBean.java

```
package edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.config;

public class ConfigIndexBean {

    private static String indexName = "dummy";

    public static final String getIndexName() {
        return indexName;
    }

    public static void setIndexName(String indexName) {
        ConfigIndexBean.indexName = indexName;
    }

}
```

and the annotation on KPIElasticValue.java:

```
@Document(type = "_doc",indexName = "# 
{T(edu.unifi.disit.datamanager.config.ConfigIndexBean).getIndexName()}")
```

In the services, before call the repository I change the index like this:

```
ConfigIndexBean.setIndexName("newindex");
```